# How to access a cloud storage bucket from app engine without getting the 403 FORBIDDEN error?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I would like to simply pull a list of the contents of my bucket from app engine and display them.

This works fine when I run it on the local dev server.
[image]

However, when I deploy the same code app engine, I get a 403 FORBIDDEN error.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 FORBIDDEN
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.alpine.servlets.TempServlet.getBucket(TempServlet.java:67)
    at com.alpine.servlets.TempServlet.doGet(TempServlet.java:79)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:439)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:310)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:302)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:443)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From my [research](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-status#standardcodes) I have determined that there are many potential causes for this error.

- AccessDenied
- AccountProblem
- AnotherUserOwnsDomain
- BucketAlreadyExists
- CrossLocationLoggingProhibited
- DomainVerificationRequired
- InsufficientQuota
- InvalidAccessKeyId
- InvalidPayer
- InvalidSecurity
- RequestTimeTooSkewed
- SignatureDoesNotMatch

However, I am not able to identify which of them applies to my situation from the stack trace.

The [Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) on this subject suggests that I should not have to do anything special to get this to work:

> If you're running your application on Google App Engine or Google
>   Compute Engine, the environment already provides a service account's
>   authentication information, so no further setup is required. For
>   Compute Engine, the service account scope depends on how you created
>   the instance. See Setting the scope of service account access for
>   instances. For App Engine, the cloud-platform scope is used.

The app engine instance and the cloud storage buckets are in different projects, but I don't think that should be a problem because the scope is set to cloud-platform.

And the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) describe cloud-platform scope as:

> View and manage data across all Google Cloud Platform services. For
>   Google Cloud Storage, this is the same as devstorage.full-control.

The code I am using to get a connection is borrowed directly from Google's [java-doc-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/json-api):

```
public class StorageFactory {

  private static Storage instance = null;

  public static synchronized Storage getService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = buildService();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  private static Storage buildService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, jsonFactory);

    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      Collection<String> bigqueryScopes = StorageScopes.all();
      credential = credential.createScoped(bigqueryScopes);
    }

    return new Storage.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("GCS Samples")
        .build();
  }
}
```

I am somewhat stumped as to how to debug this problem.

Comment: What are the permissions that you've set on the bucket? Do they include your app engine service account?

Comment: The permissions do not currently include the app engine service account from the other project. It is somewhat unclear exactly how to add that particular type of permission to the bucket.

Comment: By default, members of the project, which include the service account, probably have read access. If you've specifically set permissions, you'll want to include the service account. It counts as a user, like any other, so add grant its email address read access.

Comment: that worked beautifully. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a library [specifically built for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage). It's much easier to use.